# tcolorbox: get height of actual box from inside box

Tags: tcolorbox, tikzscale

`tcolorbox` with `\tcbuselibrary{raster}` can distribute boxes to fill the hole page. 
After that I want my tikz image to fill the hole box. The width of the box content is given by `\linewidth` but how about the height of the available space in the box?

If the height of the box is calculated by `tcolorbox`. 
How can I pass the value `/tcb/text height` to `tikzscale` that is then able to generate my plot?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{filecontents}{tikzimage.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=time,ylabel=value]
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=2,
        raster height=\textheight,
        ]
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={box 1\\line two}]
            \includegraphics[%
            width=\linewidth,
            height=4cm, % how to get the height of the actual box here?
            ]{tikzimage.tikz}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to distort your image (i.e. alter it's aspect ratio) to fill the area? I don't think you need all the tikz image, within a filecontents, within an includegraphics within a tcolorbox palava. Even if you alter the height of the thing in your code it is not going to achieve it.

Comment: This is a minimal example. filecontents just to simplify. I use externalize and plots with lots of data loaded with pgfplotstable. I just  want so seperate one single problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `tcolorbox` version `3.90 (2016/02/29)`, there is a property `\tcbtextheight` which holds the text height of a fixed height box (inspired by this question!). With it, the solution is short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{filecontents}{tikzimage.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=time,ylabel=value]
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=2,
        raster height=\textheight,
        ]
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={box 1\\line two}]
            \includegraphics[%
            width=\linewidth,
            height=\tcbtextheight,
            ]{tikzimage.tikz}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

**Old Answer (valid for `tcolorbox` before version `3.90`):**

In my answer, a new option `remember height` is constructed which saves the actual inner height into a chosen macro at the begin of the upper box. The following example uses `\myheight` which can be used to scale the included image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\begin{filecontents}{tikzimage.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=time,ylabel=value]
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}


\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
  remember height/.style={before upper={%
    \iftcb@fixedheight%
      \tcbdimto#1{\kvtcb@top@rule@stand+\kvtcb@bottom@rule@stand+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@top+\kvtcb@bottom}%
      \iftcb@hasTitle%
        \tcbdimto#1{#1+\ht\tcb@titlebox+\dp\tcb@titlebox+\kvtcb@title@rule+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@toptitle+\kvtcb@bottomtitle}%
      \fi%
      \tcbdimto#1{\kvtcb@height@fixed-#1}%
    \else%
      \tcbdimto#1{4cm}% fallback
    \fi%
  }},
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=2,
        raster height=\textheight,
        ]
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={box 1\\line two},remember height=\myheight]
            \includegraphics[%
            width=\linewidth,
            height=\myheight,
            ]{tikzimage.tikz}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe, such on option or something similar whould not be bad as an official option?

Comment: And yes, such an option would be great!

Comment: @Tobias Done with `tcolorbox 3.90` (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to compute the height of a box without a title, but not with one.  `\tcb@upperbox` is defined but contains nothing.  I suspect the lower box is created first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tcbheight}{\the\dimexpr\tcb@raster@box@height-\kvtcb@raster@skip@before-\kvtcb@raster@skip@after}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{tikzimage.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xlabel=time,ylabel=value]
            \addplot{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=2,
        raster height=\textheight,
        ]
        \begin{tcolorbox}\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}\rule{1pt}{\tcbheight} \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox} (\tcbheight) \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={box 1\\line two}]
            \includegraphics[%
            width=\linewidth,
            height=4cm, % how to get the height of the actual box here?
            ]{tikzimage.tikz}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```