# tcolorbox: height fill in the middle of the page

Tags: tcolorbox

**I am looking for a tcolorbox that has the hight like a `\vfill`.**

I have a page with `tcolorbox`es.
If there is some space left on the page, I would like to extend the hight of a box in the middle of the page. The box should have the hight of a `\vfill`.

There is alreadey a very nice feature, the option `height fill` that does exactly what I want but just for the last box on the page.

Would be great, if the solution also works for a raster like the example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}
other 
\clearpage
\begin{tcolorbox}a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=2,
    raster rows=1,
    raster height=6cm, % manual adjustment :-( 
    %raster height=\vfill,% I would like to have the hight like \vfill
    %height fill,% Nice, but only working at the end of the page :-(
]
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        Here we will have a plot that is nice to extend if there is some space left on the page.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        Here we will have a plot that is nice to extend if there is some space left on the page.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\begin{tcolorbox}a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a
\end{tcolorbox}
\clearpage
other 
\end{document}
```

[image: I want to extend the two boxes in the middle to fill the page.]

**@cfr**

As you advised,  I have put all boxes in the raster. The first and the last box should be `natural height`. Could you please show me how to extend the two boxes in the middle to fill the page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}
other 
\clearpage
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=1,
    raster rows=3,
    raster height=\textheight,
    ]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[reset,natural height]
        a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcbraster}[%
        raster columns=2,
        raster rows=1,
        raster height=6cm,% how to extend the height to fill the page?
    ]
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Here we will have a plot that is nice to extend if there is some space left on the page.
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            Here we will have a plot that is nice to extend if there is some space left on the page.
        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{tcbraster}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[reset,natural height]
        a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\clearpage
other 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why can't you put the final box inside the raster?

Comment: Thanks for your advide. I have edit to show an MWE with all boxes in a raster that has `\textheight`. First and last box is `natural height`. Could you please advise me how to extend the box in the middle to fill the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This needs some manual effort. In my code, the height of the top and bottom boxes are saved by `equal height groups` of name `topbox` and `bottombox`. Now, the height of the middle boxes are set to `\textheight-\topboxheight-\bottomboxheight-4mm` where `2mm` is the space between the boxes.

> `tcolorbox` version `3.80 (2015/11/27)` or newer is needed for this
>   answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\begin{document}
other
\clearpage
%-------------------
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=topbox,
  before skip=0mm,after skip=2mm]a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=2,
    raster rows=1,
    code={%
      \tcbheightfromgroup\topboxheight{topbox}%
      \tcbheightfromgroup\bottomboxheight{bottombox}%
    },
    raster height=\textheight-\topboxheight-\bottomboxheight-4mm]
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        Here we will have a plot that is nice to extend if there is some space left on the page.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        Here we will have a plot that is nice to extend if there is some space left on the page.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=bottombox,
  before skip=2mm,after skip=0mm]a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a
\end{tcolorbox}
%-------------------
\clearpage
other
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes... that's fine. Thank's a lot!  And it works in combination with your other solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288574/tcolorbox-get-height-of-actual-box-from-inside-box