# tcolorbox: `height fill` as option to `tcbraster`

Tags: tcolorbox

I already asked some questions and I wonder if I am to stupid.

There is a nice option called  `height fill` for the last `tcolorbox` on the page.

Isn't it possible to have `height fill` as option to the last `tcbraster` instead to the last box? In my case just two boxes next to each other. 
Is the only solution to try it like [[tcolorbox: height fill in the middle of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289217/tcolorbox-height-fill-in-the-middle-of-the-page][1]) ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{filecontents}{tikzimage.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=time,ylabel=value]
    \addplot{x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
remember height/.style={before upper={%
        \iftcb@fixedheight%
        \tcbdimto#1{\kvtcb@top@rule@stand+\kvtcb@bottom@rule@stand+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@top+\kvtcb@bottom}%
        \iftcb@hasTitle%
        \tcbdimto#1{#1+\ht\tcb@titlebox+\dp\tcb@titlebox+\kvtcb@title@rule+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@toptitle+\kvtcb@bottomtitle}%
        \fi%
        \tcbdimto#1{\kvtcb@height@fixed-#1}%
        \else%
        \tcbdimto#1{4cm}% fallback
        \fi%
    }},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    b\\b\\b\\b\\b
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=2,
    raster rows=1,
%   height fill,% this does not work :-(
    height=4cm, % want to have height=\vfill 
    ]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
    equal height group=mybox,
    title={box 1\\line two},remember height=\myheight]
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\myheight]{tikzimage.tikz}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=mybox]
        This box and the box on the left is extendet to fill the page.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

@Thomas F. Sturm
I hope this is my last question sorry and thanks so much for your time!

[image: height fill for last raster on page]

Comment: I think that would be a nice option. Currently, I have no time to investigate, if an implementation can be done, but I put it on my todo list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new answer is possible with `tcolorbox` version `3.90 (2016/02/29)`. Now, `height fill` also works for rasters and the text height of a fixed height box is available through `\tcbtextheight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{filecontents}{tikzimage.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=time,ylabel=value]
    \addplot{x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    b\\b\\b\\b\\b
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcbraster}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[height fill,title={box 1\\line two}]
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\tcbtextheight]{tikzimage.tikz}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[height fill]
        This box and the box on the left is extendet to fill the page.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that could help: [How to define a figure size so that it consumes the rest of a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/how-to-define-a-figure-size-so-that-it-consumes-the-rest-of-a-page)

Just put to preamble:

```
\newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}
```

Use `\measurepage` as length for the rest of the page. With that you can fill the rest of the page with content, for example:

```
\includegraphics[height=\measurepage,width=\textwidth]{cow}
```

In my case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\newcommand\measurepage{\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax}

\begin{filecontents}{tikzimage.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=time,ylabel=value]
    \addplot{x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
remember height/.style={before upper={%
        \iftcb@fixedheight%
        \tcbdimto#1{\kvtcb@top@rule@stand+\kvtcb@bottom@rule@stand+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@top+\kvtcb@bottom}%
        \iftcb@hasTitle%
        \tcbdimto#1{#1+\ht\tcb@titlebox+\dp\tcb@titlebox+\kvtcb@title@rule+\kvtcb@boxsep*2+\kvtcb@toptitle+\kvtcb@bottomtitle}%
        \fi%
        \tcbdimto#1{\kvtcb@height@fixed-#1}%
        \else%
        \tcbdimto#1{4cm}% fallback
        \fi%
    }},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a\\a
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    b\\b\\b\\b\\b
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcbraster}[%
    raster columns=2,
    raster rows=1,
%   height fill,% this does not work :-(
    height=\measurepage, % want to have height=\vfill 
    ]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
    equal height group=mybox,
    title={box 1\\line two},remember height=\myheight]
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\myheight]{tikzimage.tikz}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[equal height group=mybox]
        This box and the box on the left is extendet to fill the page.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

Use it at your own risk. This might not be really reliable. But at least here it works.

edit: Does not work with `\usetikzlibrary{external}`! :-(

[image]

Comment: +1 for simple and elegant solution! I wasn't aware of the `\pagegoal` and `\pagetotal` lengths and wondered, which package one needs for that or if they are `pdflatex` specials. Apparent to the comments of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813/3751), however, they are TeX primitives, hence, available with any engine. Nice!