# Notebook paper in a tcolorbox; aligning text correctly

Tags: tcolorbox, text

I found this [old post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504761/creating-the-appearance-of-notebook-paper-in-a-tcolorbox-problems-drawing-the-c) and I rather like the appearance. I'd like to use it on the worksheet I'm creating but the text is not lining up correctly with the lines created within tcolorbox.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L,C]{}
\newcommand\descitem[1]{\item{\bfseries #1}\\}
\renewcommand\headrule{%
\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}
{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
\hrulefill}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}

\newtcolorbox{notebook}{valign lower=top,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=blue!10,
    colframe=blue!65!black,
    left=.7in,
    underlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        %\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
%(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines, ystep=\baselineskip, xstep=\linewidth, 
            shift={(interior.north west)}](interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
        \draw[help lines] ([xshift=.5in]interior.north west)--
            ([xshift=.5in]interior.south west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}}
    }

\usepackage{lineno}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\LARGE{Prepare Your Curriculum Vitae}
\end{center}


\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=!,labelindent=0pt, leftmargin=0em, label=\arabic*, itemsep=1.2cm, parsep=0pt, font=\large\color{red}]

\item[\huge{$1$}]\LARGE{\underline{Introduction}}

\item \large{Why are you writing a curriculum vitae?}
\begin{notebook}
\blindtext[1]
\end{notebook}
\item \large{Describe your feelings as you begin this process.}
\item \large{The preparation for writing a curriculum vitae can engender feelings of self-analysis and self-evaluation. Describe your responses to these forms of reflection.}
\item \large{It is essential that you confront any uneasiness, discomfort, or negative feelings you have about your background. Write them down and tehn set them aside. Do not dwell on them.}
\item \large{List your strengths and document each with an experience in which you take great pride.}
\item \large{Find out what skills, knowledge, and experience are needed for the job.}
\item \large{Create a list of questions to ask about the job.}


\end{enumerate}
\vspace{.5cm}
\end{document}
```

anyway to fix this?

[image: compiled document]

I believe I can do it by shifting all the text up a certain amount, but I can't figure out how to do it from the [documentation](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf). Page 39.

[image: tcolorbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tests, a little change at `bottom` margin makes

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L,C]{}
\newcommand\descitem[1]{\item{\bfseries #1}\\}
\renewcommand\headrule{%
\hrulefill
\raisebox{-2.1pt}
{\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}%
\hrulefill}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc}

\newtcolorbox{notebook}{valign lower=top,
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    colback=blue!10,
    colframe=blue!65!black,
    left=.7in,
    bottom=2.75mm,
    underlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        %\shade[inner color=green!80!yellow,outer color=yellow!10!white]
%(interior.north west) circle (2cm);
        \draw[help lines, ystep=\baselineskip, xstep=\linewidth, 
             ](interior.north west) grid (interior.south east);
        \draw[help lines] ([xshift=.5in]interior.north west)--
            ([xshift=.5in]interior.south west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}}
    }

\usepackage{lineno}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\LARGE{Prepare Your Curriculum Vitae}
\end{center}


\begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=!,labelindent=0pt, leftmargin=0em, label=\arabic*, itemsep=1.2cm, parsep=0pt, font=\large\color{red}]

\item[\huge{$1$}]\LARGE{\underline{Introduction}}

\item \large{Why are you writing a curriculum vitae?}
\begin{notebook}
\blindtext[1]
\end{notebook}
\item \large{Describe your feelings as you begin this process.}
\item \large{The preparation for writing a curriculum vitae can engender feelings of self-analysis and self-evaluation. Describe your responses to these forms of reflection.}
\item \large{It is essential that you confront any uneasiness, discomfort, or negative feelings you have about your background. Write them down and tehn set them aside. Do not dwell on them.}
\item \large{List your strengths and document each with an experience in which you take great pride.}
\item \large{Find out what skills, knowledge, and experience are needed for the job.}
\item \large{Create a list of questions to ask about the job.}


\end{enumerate}
\vspace{.5cm}
\end{document}
```